# How to connect Washing machine output water to WC seat?

Tags: water, toilet, washing-machine, connectors

There is a small WC room where you cannot forward the washing machine output water elsewhere than WC seat (brand IDO). However, the current solution does not look nice, see the picture. 
I am thinking if there any seats or solutions which can avoid such a connection.

[image]

WC is on the left-hand-side corner: the sink is in the opposite corner than the washing machine: the room is very small:

[image]

Comment: Because of the way a toilet works - fill/flush, fill/flush, not a continuous flow - I'd be concerned as to whether this will work properly or not. You don't have a sink in the same room?

Comment: @manassehkatz I have a sink in the same room but the tube would cross the floor, what I would avoid. Please, see the picture of the WC room added where you see the sink is in the opposite diagonal side of the washing machine.

Comment: Not sure what is the item in between on the wall next to the sink. But in general I would go with the sink as long as you don't have to go past a door (which you don't) to get there.

Comment: This just sounds like a hassle to implement and live with. I'd add a renegade (unvented) standpipe to the sink drain before I'd do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get an extension pipe and an extension 'connector' for the current pipe
2. Get a 'U' guide for the dump pipe and run it to the toilet  or the sink

I'd run the 'extended' pipe behind the toilet and I'd hook it to the sink.

[image: U guide]
[image: extension pipe connector]
[image: extensible washing machine drain pipe]

Answer (score 0):

If you have to run it into a Toilet/WC, run it into the Tank/Cistern, and let the overflow there take care of it. Though that particular one does not look overly easy to access from this picture (no obvious lid, just a bunch of seamless ceramic monolith...)

Comment: While that would take care of the aesthetics, my concern (which may or may not be justified) about how the flush process works - i.e., bowl fills and then empties, not a continuos flow - is still valid; **and** the overflow tube is generally fairly small so I worry about whether it would be adequate to handle a full-force washing machine discharge cycle.

Comment: An added bonus of this solution, is that the next time you flush the toilet, you get a nice detergent/fabric softener smell that will reduce the odours from the toilet bowl.

Comment: Aside from what mannassehkatz said, I'd be concerned that the inherent lint and other nastiness would clog the orifices in the bowl and eventually gum up the valve assembly. It'll certainly cause plenty of soiling of the bowl.